# How filter node inside view block by even nid (or odd nid)

Tags: views

I have a view 2 blocks where I show some images and I'm trying to show the images with an even nid in the 1st block and the images with odd nid in the 2nd block

Do you guys have any idea if it's possible? and how?

Comment: Are you custom-coding the block  or do you use views to do it ?

Comment: @IsmaH I'm using views

Comment: Hi. See my version of the regex answer. But I do have a question: are you creating a View of nodes (in other words, are the images part of a node, as in an Image field type?). Or are you creating a View of file entities? If your View is of file entities (not Content entities) then you should filter by File ID (fid), not Node ID (nid)

Comment: Thank you @argiepiano for the help but I solved with some code in the tpl file, I really appreciate your effort :D

Answer (score 2):

@IsmaH answer is on the right track (use Regex for filtering `nid`). The problem in his answer is that this filter uses [mySQL Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html) - this is why his proposed regex is not working.

This worked for me:
`^.*[13579]$`

or this for even numbers: `^.*[02468]$`

**Notice:** no slashes at the beginning and end of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You should create two blocks.

Let's call them EvenBlock et OddBlock. On each one of them, visit the view editing page (back office).

On "FILTER CRITERIA" Clic on add and type "NID" in the search bar then select "Content: Nid".
Then chose " Regular expression" and write a REGEX to match odd nid (I think "^\d*[13579]$") for the OddBlock and even nid ("^\d*[02468]$") for the EvenBlock.

Then save ^^

Comment: Are you sure about the regex values?

Comment: I think so. If it doesn't work try without the " "

Comment: Tried that too and it didn't work

Comment: https://regex101.com/
You can test the regex is. I think it is working. Otherwise, you can try to put it like #^\d*[13579]$# or /^\d*[13579]$/

Comment: Still not working ?